Why are elements of $K(u)$ the rational functions over $K$?
As presented in Hungerford's V.I Theorem 1.3 (iv): for an extension field $F$ of a field $K$, with $u \in F$, why are the elements of $K(u)$ given by
$$\frac{h(u)}{k(u)}=h(u)k(u)^{-1}$$
where $h,k \in K[x]$ and $k(u) \ne 0$?
I've reviewed section 13.1 and 13.2 in Dummit and Foote and don't see an explicit reference to the elements in this field.
I had understood $f \in K(u)$ to be $f(u)$ where $f \in K[x]$. That is, $$f(u) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_iu^i, \qquad a_i \in K.$$
I'm aware that $K(u)$ is the smallest field containing $K$ and $u$. Since $K(u)$ is a field, it's closed under addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division such that I can understand why each element's coefficients can be expressed as a quotient. However, I'm having trouble understanding why this is their general form.
I know that if $u\in F$ is the root of some irreducible $p(x) \in K[x]$, i.e.: $p(u)=0$, then $$K(u) \cong K[x]/(p(x)).$$
I also know about the similar isomorphism involving the minimal polynomial
$$K(u) \cong K[x]/(m_u(x)).$$
But, I'm not sure this is needed since it doesn't look like $u$ being a root is explicitly required in Hungerford.
*I can also recognize that part of what distinguishes $K[x]$, which is only a UFD, from $K(u)$ is that $K(u)$ is a field meaning it has a division algorithm. But, I'm still not seeing how the rational function form is definitional.

"I had understood $f\in K(u)$ to be $f(u)$ where $f\in K[X]$". Probably you have messed something up. $f$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $K$, i.e. $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ with $a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n\in K$. For each $u\in F$, $f(u)$ is an element of $F$: $f(u)=a_nu^n+\cdots+a_1u+a_0$ (which is computed by the "data" of the operation on $F$). $$\left{\frac{f(u)}{g(u)}: f,g\in K[x], g(u)\ne 0\right}$$ is a subset of $F$. An element $a\in F$ is in the subset if exists $f,g\in K[X]$ subject to $g(u)\ne 0$ and $a=f(u)g(u)^{-1}$.

You're right, I did mess something up. I guess, per your comment, that $f(u)$ is the form of the elements in $K[u]$, not $K(u)$, where $f\in K[x]$.

Yes, that is correct.

By definition $$K(u)=\bigcap\nolimits_{F\text{ is a field containing }K\cup\{u\}} F . $$
So it suffices to prove $$ \bigcap\nolimits_{F\text{ is a field containing }K\cup\{u\}} F=\left\{\frac{f(u)}{g(u)}: f,g\in K[x], g(u)\ne 0\right\} .  $$
Denote the right hand side by $E$. To prove the above equality we prove $(\subseteq)$ and $(\supseteq)$.
To prove $(\subseteq)$ we observe $E$ itself is a field containing $K\cup \{u\}$.
To prove $(\supseteq)$ it suffices to prove for each field $F$ containing $K$ and $u$, we have $E\subseteq F$.
Let $\frac{f(u)}{g(u)}\in E$. Then $f(u),g(u)\in F$ and therefore $\frac{f(u)}{g(u)}\in F$.
To make the idea more explicit I omitted some details. Please feel free to comment if some more explanation is needed.

Elements of the form $\frac{h(u)}{k(u)}$ form a subfield of $F$ containing $K$ and $u$, as you can easily check. Moreover, this is clearly the smallest subfield containing $K$ and $u$. (any field containing $K$ and $u$ must contain the above fractions, because it is closed under the field operations) Hence this field is equal to $K(u)$. This always holds, we always have:
$K(u)=\{\frac{h(u)}{k(u)}: h,k\in K[x], k(u)\ne 0\}$
You are right that this description of $K(u)$ might not be the "minimal" description, and maybe some elements appear more than once. If $u$ is algebraic over $K$ then in order to describe the field $K(u)$, we don't really need to substitute $u$ in all rational functions over $K$. It can be proved that in this case it is sufficient to substitute $u$ only in polynomials, and even not in all of them, but in those whose degree is less than the degree of the minimal polynomial $m_u$. So if $u$ is algebraic then:
$K(u)=\{h(u): h\in K[x], \deg(h)<\deg(m_u)\}$
However, if $u$ is transcendental then we do actually have to substitute $u$ in all rational functions in order to get $K(u)$, in this case there is no way to improve it. So the first description I've mentioned is a universal one, it works in all cases. In some cases you can improve it, in other cases not.

Thanks for responding. I believe that $\frac{h(u)}{k(u)}$ forms a subfield. As a definition, I have that the smallest subfield containing $K$ and $u$ is $K(u)$ (the field generated by $u$ over $K$ whose elements have the form in the OP). So, how can we say that "clearly" it is the same field as $\frac{h(u)}{k(u)}$? I get the intuition that any field containing $K$ and $u$ must contain these fractions since it's a field

@orocd398897 Well, if any field contains these fractions then the fractions are indeed the smallest field. This is the definition of "smallest": any field $E\subseteq F$ containing $K$ and $u$ satisfies $K(u)\subseteq E$.

Thanks and sorry- I didn't immediately pickup at first on the nested fields argument your parenthetical was referring to.
